# Making a Pandas DataFrame allowable for an update by reference after a filter

Tags: python, pandas

I'm filtering a df as follows with a function named `sell_shares`:

```
def sell_shares(df_company, number_shares, date_end):
    df_filtered = df_company.copy()[(df_company['Date'] <= date_end)]
    df_filtered['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df_filtered['Date'], dayfirst=True)
    emaining_shares = number_shares # default
    for i, row in df_filtered.iterrows():
      row = df_filtered.iloc[i]
        remaining_shares, df_filtered = remove_shares(df_filtered, i, remaining_shares)
```

and then calling a function with `df_filtered`

```
def remove_shares(df, i, number_shares):
  #print("Considering row: ", row)
  print("Before sell, Number of shares: {:}".format(df.iloc[i]["Quantity"]))
  remaining_shares = 0
  if abs(number_shares) < abs(df.iloc[i]["Quantity"]):
    # have less than in batch - so decrement
    #row.columns.set_loc("Quantity") += - abs(number_shares)
    #row["Quantity"] += - abs(number_shares)
    df.iloc[i, df.columns.get_loc("Quantity")] += - abs(number_shares)
```

and my original calling function

```
def compute_gain_before_tax_year(df, company_name, date_start, date_end):

  df_company = df.copy(deep=True)
  df_company = df_company[df_company["Market"]==company_name]
  df_company = df_company[( df_company["Date"] < pd.to_datetime(date_start, dayfirst=True))]
```

when I eventually update that dataframe

```
df.iloc[i, df.columns.get_loc("Quantity")] = 0
```

How do I ensure this is all done by reference. In the function `remove_shares` I can see the changes reflected in the table at a local level when I print, but they do not propagate upwards.

Comment: Can you provide a complete code with a minimal example of data and `remove_shares` to reproduce your issue?

Comment: Do `df_filtered = df_company[...].copy()`.

Comment: @QuangHoang Thanks. I tried putting `.copy()` on all potential copies. But sadly I'm still getting the issue. I know there is a known issue of view vs copy, but this seems to make no sense to me to get this to work!

Comment: Please add a data sample, including the expected output. I don't understand `remaining_shares, df_filtered = remove_shares(df_filtered, i, remaining_shares)` - `remove_shares` returns `None`?